# How can I use the question mark operator to handle errors in Tokio futures?

Tags: error-handling, rust, future, rust-tokio

I have a client handling a `Future` that does some stuff. Is it possible to use `impl Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error>` as a return type and make better error handling?

```
pub fn handle_client(client: Client) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error> {
    let magic = client.header.magic;
    let stream_client = TcpStream::connect(&client.addr).and_then(|stream| {
        let addr: Vec<u8> = serialize_addr(stream.local_addr()?, magic)?;
        write_all(stream, addr).then(|result| {
            // some code
            Ok(())
        })
    });
    stream_client
}
```

I cannot keep the `io::Error` type through all nested closures/futures. The compiler throws the error

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
   --> src/client.rs:134:29
    |
134 |         let addr: Vec<u8> = serialize_addr(stream.local_addr()?, magic)?;
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `futures::future::then::Then<tokio_io::io::write_all::WriteAll<tokio_tcp::stream::TcpStream, std::vec::Vec<u8>>, std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error>, [closure@src/client.rs:135:38: 138:10]>`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `futures::future::then::Then<tokio_io::io::write_all::WriteAll<tokio_tcp::stream::TcpStream, std::vec::Vec<u8>>, std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error>, [closure@src/client.rs:135:38: 138:10]>`
    = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

I made chaining map/and_then error handling, but problem is I don't know how to get `TcpStream` inside final `.then` closure. The only place I found `TcpStream` is inside WriteAll struct, however it's private. Besides, write_all consumes stream

```
use futures::Future;
use std::{io, net::SocketAddr};
use tokio::{
    io::{write_all, AsyncRead, AsyncWrite},
    net::TcpStream,
};

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;

fn serialize_addr(addr: SocketAddr) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
    Ok(vec![])
}

fn handle_client(addr: &SocketAddr) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = Error> {
    TcpStream::connect(addr)
        .map_err(Into::into)
        .and_then(|stream| stream.local_addr().map(|stream_addr| (stream, stream_addr)))
        .map_err(Into::into)
        .and_then(|(stream, stream_addr)| serialize_addr(stream_addr).map(|info| (stream, info)))
        .map(|(stream, info)| write_all(stream, info))
        .then(|result| {
            let result = result.unwrap();
            let stream = match result.state {
                Writing { a } => a,
                _ => panic!("cannot get stream"),
            };
            // some code
            Ok(())
        })
}

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8900".parse().unwrap();
    handle_client(&addr);
}
```

Comment: For example, your code uses undefined types and methods that we don't know the signature of. Your error message doesn't even correspond to the code.

Comment: Why have you used `map(... write_all)` when the code below uses `and_then`? You can't arbitrarily change what methods you call and expect it to work. When using `and_then`, the success value of the future is `(TcpStream, Vec<u8>)`.

Comment: I don't know why, but without casting to          ```serialize_addr(remote_addr).map_err(|_| io::Error::from(io::ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable))``` I couldn't use `.and_then` instead of `.map`

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: you don't use the `?` operator.

---

Since **you didn't provide one**, here is a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem. Note that we *have no idea* what the error type is of your `serialize_addr` function, so I had to pick something:

```
use futures::Future;
use std::{io, net::SocketAddr};
use tokio::{io::write_all, net::TcpStream};

fn serialize_addr() -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(vec![])
}

pub fn handle_client(addr: &SocketAddr) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error> {
    TcpStream::connect(addr).and_then(|stream| {
        let addr = serialize_addr()?;
        write_all(stream, addr).then(|_result| Ok(()))
    })
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
  --> src/lib.rs:11:20
   |
11 |         let addr = serialize_addr()?;
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `futures::future::then::Then<tokio_io::io::write_all::WriteAll<tokio_tcp::stream::TcpStream, std::vec::Vec<u8>>, std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error>, [closure@src/lib.rs:12:38: 14:10]>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `futures::future::then::Then<tokio_io::io::write_all::WriteAll<tokio_tcp::stream::TcpStream, std::vec::Vec<u8>>, std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error>, [closure@src/lib.rs:12:38: 14:10]>`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

As the error message states:

> the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)

and

> cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `Then<WriteAll<TcpStream, Vec<u8>>, Result<(), io::Error>, [closure]>`

Instead, leverage the fact that `Result` can be treated as a future and let it participate in the chain of functions.

Additionally, just like everywhere else in Rust, you need to have a unified error type. I've chosen `Box<dyn Error>` for simplicity. This can be achieved using [`map_err`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.map_err) and [`Into::into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into)

```
use futures::Future;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::{io::write_all, net::TcpStream};

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;

fn serialize_addr() -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
    Ok(vec![])
}

pub fn handle_client(addr: &SocketAddr) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = Error> {
    TcpStream::connect(addr)
        .map_err(Into::into)
        .and_then(|stream| serialize_addr().map(|addr| (stream, addr)))
        .and_then(|(stream, addr)| write_all(stream, addr).map_err(Into::into))
        .then(|_result| Ok(()))
}
```

In the future, `async` / `await` syntax will make this easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the two streams:

```
fn handle_client(addr: &SocketAddr) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = Error> {
    TcpStream::connect(addr)
        .map_err(Into::into)
        .and_then(|remote_stream| {
            remote_stream
                .local_addr()
                .map(|remote_addr| (remote_stream, remote_addr))
        })
        .map_err(Into::into)
        .and_then(|(remote_stream, remote_addr)| {
            TcpStream::connect(&"".parse().unwrap())
                .map(move |proxy_stream| (remote_stream, proxy_stream, remote_addr))
        })
        .and_then(|(remote_stream, proxy_stream, remote_addr)| {
            serialize_addr(remote_addr)
                .map(|info| (remote_stream, proxy_stream, info))
                .map_err(|_| io::Error::from(io::ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable))
        })
        .and_then(|(remote_stream, proxy_stream, info)| {
            write_all(proxy_stream, info).map(|proxy_stream| (remote_stream, proxy_stream.0))
        })
        .and_then(|(remote_stream, proxy_stream)| {
            // working with streams
        })
        .then(|_result| Ok(()))
}
```